# I used StartsWith but its not working in azure cosmosDB documents through linq

Tags: linq, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have used STARTSWITH to filter the records through linq to fetch the data from azure cosmos db. but it always shows the record count as zero.

The query used to fetch the data:

```cs
var locs = from data 
    in locations 
    where data.Properties.Street.ToLower().StartsWith("chest") 
    select data;
```

---

Here's a sample from the document database:

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            -0.141246,
            51.56292
        ]
    },
    "properties": {
        "city": "london",
        "countryCode": "GB",
        "parkingType": "permit holders only",
        "approxNoOfSpaces": 4,
        "timesOfOperation": "mon-fri 10:00-12:00",
        "maximumStay": "N/A",
        "tariff": "N/A",
        "cashlessIdentifier": "N/A",
        "nearestMachine": "N/A",
        "street": "Chester Road",
        "postcode": "N19 5DE",
        "controlledParkingZone": "CA-U",
        "validParkingPermits": "CA-U",
        "parkingBayLengthMetres": 19,
        "disclaimer": "The information provider and/ or licensor are not liable for any errors or omissions contained within this dataset and shall not be liable for any loss, injury or damage caused by its use.",
        "easting": 528937,
        "northing": 186530,
        "EPSG:27700 Well Known Text Geometry": "LINESTRING (528943.9746311313 186522.8076569282,528944.9970187079 186524.33721909559,528929.9827624428 186537.32350181084,528928.7624933998 186535.9039081653)",
        "EPSG:4326 Well Known Text Geometry": "LINESTRING (-0.14114833166779203 51.56285353559299,-0.14113302974759298 51.56286704785321,-0.14134475707247782 51.56298717904703,-0.14136287187179347 51.56297470018317)",
        "externalFeatureId": 46044821,
        "spatialAccuracy": "Defined By Custodian",
        "lastUploaded": "07/08/2019 11:01:52 PM",
        "location": "(51.56292, -0.141246)",
        "organisationURI": "http://opendatacommunities.org/id/london-borough-council/camden",
        ":@computed_region_hxwp_gyfc": 10,
        ":@computed_region_6i9a_26nj": 66
    },
    "documentType": "location",
    "id": "********************",
    "_rid": "*******************",
    "_self": "****************************",
    "_etag": "*****************************",
    "_attachments": "********************",
    "_ts": 1565344913
}
```

Comment: Once you've lower-cased "Chester Road" it no longer starts with "Chest", it starts with "chest". Have you tried using "chest" as the argument to StartsWith instead?

Comment: Yes I have tried. But it not works

Comment: Actually  it works when we use the STARTSWITH with the property type but it's not working on the properties.street... it's not working with inner objects